# ADB connection to Hauwei G Play Mini, not connected, other device (acer, samsung) connects good

Tags: android, windows-7, adb, adb-drivers

we bought some Huawei G Mini Play devices to use our own app on for our company.

We tried to get an ADB connection, so we could debug our app in case of any problems. But this doesn't work at all. I tried HiSuite and couldn't connect to this. I even looked for drivers, but none I tried got it working.

I tried 2 other devices, an acer and asamsung and both got directly the ADB connection, so this works fine.

If I try this with the huawei G Mini Play,  I get a normal connection to the pc (Windows 7), so I can see all the files of my device on the computer.

But I can't get the ADB working. Is this a driver problem, because I can't find any drivers using there site (huawei) or by using google, wich are working.

Any ideas?

Yes, I put the USB Debugging on @ the Huawei :-)

Thx in advance.

Sincerlery yours,
Timothy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a lot of drivers, from Huawei and also others.

Finally I found one that is working correctly en I can use debugging from Delphi XE10.

I found it @ http://download-c.huawei.com/download/downloadCenter?downloadId=16205&siteCode=worldwide

This is for me (Huawei G Play Mini with Windows 7) the good driver from the official support site from Huawei

The only "funny" thing is that when I use other drivers, official and non-official, I always got my Device CHC-U01 in the Device Manager, but I couldn't get him in my ADB Devices.
When I use this driver, the one from the downloadpage, I don't see my Device as normal in the Device Manager. But I see it as a SAMSUNG Android Phoe, Android Adapter ADB Interface.

I don't understand why, but this way, it works for me.. I can see it him as an ADB Device and can debug on it.

Comment: Hey, its been a (long) while since you posted this, but there's any way of "just" download the drivers for the phone? The link you post is to Huawei's own application for managing the phone, and their licensing is talking about recording way too many things for me to be comfortable with...